# Simulate Hyperledger Fabric network with 5000 users

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am new to Hyperledger Fabric.
I read its documentation and followed the [test network](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/test_network.html) they provided on their website, so the test-network provides a bunch of terminal commands to add a third organization and its peer. I like that everything is ready to run on terminals, but the problem is the **high level of abstraction** over many details.

Goal:
I would like to simulate a permissioned blockchain network with 5000 users. Each user should be able to broadcast a transaction in every 15 seconds to the channel. The orderers should package these transactions in every 15 seconds and let the connected users verify new blocks.

Questions:

- Should I create a new peer for each user?
- Or can I use a single peer and let each user use the app?

I could not find a single tutorial on adding more peers dynamically.
Reading the documentation, I think I should let each user have his own peer and app to broadcast transactions. However, creating 5000 peers(one-by-one) would be very time-consuming.

I know these questions may sound naive, considering my other options like creating my blockchain network simulation using [socketio](https://socket.io/) or [grpc](https://grpc.io/) would be less painful at the moment. I don't really want to avoid reading the docs of HLF, but the high-level of abstraction and the learning-time make me wonder, I should better use the other options for my simulation. As Linus Torvalds puts it simply:

> Talk is cheap, show me the code!

In HLF case, I don't want the already-provided terminal commands, I want to really understand and modify the source code of peers.

Thank you for any recommendation or direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need 5000 users (as registered in the CA), not 5000 peers. A single peer should be enough (although some more peers can be useful to distribute the endorsements and improve performance).

So, you should:

- Register 5000 users in your Fabric-CA
- Enroll their cryptographic material from the Fabric-CA
- Run the 5000 clients (`peer` command, Fabric SDK based application or whatever).

Fabric CA related stuff: https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deployguide/use_CA.html.

Obviously, you should prepare some kind of script to do that. Don't do it manually.

If your purpose is only testing, maybe you can use [cryptogen](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/commands/cryptogen.html) instead of Fabric-CA.

It seems that you are trying to perform some kind of performance test. [Hyperledger Caliper](https://hyperledger.github.io/caliper/v0.4.2/getting-started/) is designed for these kind of tests. Maybe you can configure Caliper with 5000 workers (although I'm not sure if you can configure less than 1 TPS to simulate your request every 15 seconds).

About the orderers, you can configure your ordering service with a batch time of 15 seconds, but take into account that your 5000 transactions every 15 seconds may reach the batch size before that happens, so the block is generated before.

Comment: For future readers: initialize 5000 workers with Hyperledger Caliper at your own risk. In my case, 200 workers quickly filled up my RAM (16 Gb) and my PC got that "bruh moment" for a while.